# Can't enable direct line app service extension in azure bot service

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I want to develop .net core desktop client application to connect bot service direct line. for that I am following [this document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#enable-bot-direct-line-app-service-extension) But I couldn't make it work. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#confirm-direct-line-app-extension-and-the-bot-are-configured) is way to confirm that it has been properly configured. the web page should show output like below in case everything went fine.

```js
{"v":"123","k":true,"ib":true,"ob":true,"initialized":true}
```

but in my case I am getting output like below:

```js
{"v":"1.0.0.0.55fa54091a1e3b168628d4000ee2b06a88bbc2ac","k":true,"ib":false,"ob":false,"initialized":true}
```

where "ib" and "ob" values are false for some reason. I found [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1707) and [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1355) issue reported on github but there is no conclusion.

any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you have followed all the steps correctly, you should get "true" values for IB/OB. Have you tried restarting your app service? Is your bot starting up correctly?

Comment: @ranusharao Yes I could make it working after following updated document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Troubleshooting guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#troubleshooting) has been added to the document. verified steps below and getting proper results now:

1. Double check the code for using named pipes has been added to the
   bot.
2. Confirm the bot is able to start up and run at all. Useful
   tools are Test in WebChat, connecting an additional channel, remote
   debugging, or logging.
3. Restart the entire Azure App Service the bot
   is hosted within, to ensure a clean start up of all processes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I followed Microsoft Docs on how to setup the bot project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

I did a simple echo bot project and followed the sample code in Startup.cs `Configure` method.

Last thing I did is to resolve an issue HTTP 500.34 when I access the /.bot as described.

You need to add: `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` in `.csproj` after `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`